# Как проверить, начинается ли введённая строка с заданного словосочетания?

Tags: python, if

Необходимо, чтобы при вводе с консоли словосочетания "открой диск" и пути к папке открывалась нужная папка. Если же словосочетания нет, пропустить это действие.

Вопрос: как реализовать проверку на предмет того, начинается ли введённая строка с заданного словосочетания?

Comment: А теперь перечитайте свой вопрос и подумайте, Вы бы сами поняли, о чём вообще речь, если бы не знали контекста? Так вот, другие участники сообщества контекста не знают. Так что, во-первых, сформулируйте грамотно, что Вы делаете и чего хотите, во-вторых, добавьте код.

Comment: А я вроде догадался )

Comment: "при вводе текста"... Каком вводе? Где в коде оператор считывания вводимого текста откуда-либо? В какую переменную Вы его сохраняете после ввода? Приведите уже, наконец, весь код

Comment: @CrazyElf восхищён Вашими экстрасенсорными способностями :) За Вами будущее SO. К сожалению, такой дар дан не всем, именно поэтому на вопросе 4 минуса уже.

Comment: @V-Mor Код полностью не буд скидывать как как его не посприймут но суть такова
alias = "открой диск"
cmd = input(":") например открой диск Z:// папку Counter Strike
if cmd == alias как мне зделать чтобы проверялось не полностью а именно наличие открой диск
как реализовать открытие я знаю мне нужно чтобы из cmd проврилось наличие alias и если он там есть выполнилось действие

Comment: Так, попытаюсь перевести, извините, с Вашего на русский. То есть Вам надо, чтобы нужная папка открывалась только тогда, когда перед ней написано "открой диск"? А если просто введут имя папки то ничего не делать?

Comment: @V-Mor да так  я извеняюсь что вопрос был задан не понятно

Comment: Так Вам уже дали ответ на это в таком случае. Используйте `startswith`, как написал @CrazyElf

Comment: @V-Mor да понятно спасибо

Comment: И примите, пожалуйста, ответ. Он ведь всё-таки оказался верным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `startswith` для определения того, что строка начинается с искомой подстроки:

```
cmd_input = input() # "открой диск C://Chrome"
cmd_open = "открой диск"
if cmd_input.startswith(cmd_open):
    print('открываю диск', cmd_input[len(cmd_open):].strip())
```

Вывод:

```
открываю диск C://Chrome
```

Comment: нет возможно что будет не только диск C:// 
есть варианты что будет E://Counter Strike 1.6 /strike 
и многие другие

Comment: @Алекс Ну это пример. Вместо конкретной строки можно input поставить, видите комментарий? Сейчас поменяю наоборот, может так будет понятнее